# Confidence interval of averaged-regression fit

Tags: confidence-interval, model-averaging

I have a model; Y ~ mX, where Y is a set of new random number generated using Poisson distribution. i.e $Y_i \sim \text{poisson}(H_i)$.

Hence I am performing 100 replications, during each replication, generating a new set of values of Y, using poisson($H_i$), and then fitting the model. Let Y-hat be the fitted values of Y during each replication. At the end, I am averaging the Y-hat values.

The question that I want to ask is how to calculate the confidence interval for this averaged-Y-hat, based on the confidence interval of the Y-hats fitted in each replication.

Comment: When you say "fitted values of Y", what do you mean? As I understand, you got samples of Y, what are you trying to fit? the only free parameter I see here is H

Comment: a new samples of Y are generated from using Poisson distribution, taking H as the mean, in each replication. Note that H is an array of means, so we generate a new array of Y in each replication. Then we fit the generated samples Y using a regression model Y~mX. Y-hat are the fitted/predicted values of Y from the regression model during a replication. At the end, I am averaging the Y-hat values from all replications, to get a single mean Y-hat value. Now I need to add a confidence interval to this mean Y-hat. One approach can be to use the values of Y-hat from all replications to get a CI.

Comment: But I want to ask, if I should do that, or should I utilize the original confidence intervals of Y-hat from the model, and use the confidence intervals from each replication to get a final confidence interval.